# LaTeX create ONLY table of contents

Tags: latex, tableofcontents

I have some documents scanned as pdf, and since I want to hand them in to my university combined as one document, I want to attach a table of contents to make the reader aware of the fact, that there are several documents inside this pdf. So, since I already have the documents and I am not producing them in Latex anymore, I only want to create the table of contents in Latex. Usually, Latex pulls its information for the toc out of the document it won't have this time. So, is there *manual* way of creating a table of contents, where I can type in myself, which section exists and what page it is on?

Thank you all in advance
and have a nice weekend!

PS: I double checked if that topic was already dealt with, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Have a look at the `pdfpages` package. This allows you to stitch the pdfs together and add information for the toc via the `addtotoc={....}` option

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much!

Comment: But still, if someone knows how to create ToC entries without them existing, it would still be more practical for me. Is there maybe something like addtotoc without including a pdf, where you can specify the page even if the document doesn't have that many pages?

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently the answer lies in the .toc file which is auto generated when compiling. This document contains commands with the pattern

`\contentsline {section}{\numberline {<number of enumeration>}\ignorespaces <heading>}{<pagenumber>}%`

this comment also works when used after the `\tableofcontents` command.